# class template with multiple template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to define the same template class in several version, each with a different template parameter. The compiler is giving me the error

```
 previous declaration ‘template<class T1> class A’ used
```

Is there a way to circumvent this problem? Unfortunately I cannot use Cx++11 where I can assign a default template parameter. What is a good practice to tackle this issue?
I am using old g++4.4.7

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T1>
class A{};

template <class T1,class T2>
class A{};

int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: Kerrek has the right answer, but C++11 only added default template types to functions... you could always write `template <typename T1, typename T2 = void> class A { };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot use C++11 variadic templates, you can use a "mock" type

```
struct NoType{};

template <class T1, class T2 = NoType> // or class T2 = void, doesn't really matter
class A{};
```

then specialize it as needed.

PS: as @Barry mentioned in the comment, default template parameters for classes ARE ALLOWED in pre C++11 . The novelty in this respect introduced by C++11 is to allow default template parameters in functions.

Comment: Hi. This is ok ..it is meant/works well to be used with Partial Specialization.

Answer (score 5):

Make a variadic template and add partial specializations:

```
template <typename ...> class A;      // leave primary template undefined

template <typename T> class A<T>
{
    // ...
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> class A<T1, T2>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Hi Kerrek. Good stuff the partial specialization! Sorry that I can't use variadic templates, but I like the response.